# Status bar inappropriately appears when selecting for ListPreference dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, statusbar, listpreference, android-theme

Try this:

1) Set your manifest to use a full screen theme (thereby hiding the status bar)

2) Create a set of nested preference activities, and have the innermost activity open a ListPreference dialog.

You will find that opening this dialog causes the status bar to briefly re-appear, and it will then permanently re-appear if you change the device orientation.

Is this a legitimate Android bug? Is there a way to override the theme used by ListPreference itself? ([Relevant?](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_InputMethod))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug appears in a number of different ways surrounding full screen activities.  Clicking on a spinner with more items than fit on the screen for example.  If you would like to submit a bug report it belongs [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list).

Comment: Ahh, thanks, it was a "more items than fit on the screen" bug. Know of any workarounds?

Comment: For those interested: Google code issue report on the matter: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3674